# Karma showing this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I am writing a very basic unit test. I don't know what to do with it. I have tried so many things but cannot be able to resolve this error. Except first test other test is failing.

Spec file

```
fdescribe("New TestOrder ICD10 Code Selection Modal Component", () => {
  let component: NewTestOrderICD10CodeSelectionModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NewTestOrderICD10CodeSelectionModalComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let element: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async (() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        NewTestOrderICD10CodeSelectionModalComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        UtilService,
        SessionService,
        TestOrderService,
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/'}
      ],
      schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewTestOrderICD10CodeSelectionModalComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.new-test-order-icd10-code-selection-modal.component'));
    element  = de.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("New Test Order ICD10 Coed Selection Modal Should be created", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Should have a title', () => {
    expect(element.textContent).toContain(component.title);
  });
});
```

Here is mew-test-order-icd10-code-selection-modal.component.ts file

```
// Angular DOM
import {Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core";
// Angular Hooks
import {OnInit, AfterViewInit} from "@angular/core";
// Redux Store
import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import {SetTestOrderCodeSelectionSession} from "../../../../shared";
// Models
import {
  TestOrder,
  TestOrderCodeSelectionSession
} from "../../../../shared/models";
// Third Party Services
import {NgbModal, NgbModalOptions} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import * as lodash from "lodash";
// Services
import {TestOrderService} from "../../../../shared";
import {SetTestOrderICDCodes} from "../../../../shared/actions/test-order.actions";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Component({
  selector: "app-new-test-order-icd10-code-selection-modal",
  templateUrl: "./new-test-order-icd10-code-selection-modal.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./new-test-order-icd10-code-selection-modal.component.scss"]
})
export class NewTestOrderICD10CodeSelectionModalComponent
  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild("icd10codes") template: TemplateRef<any>;
  public codeSelectionSession: TestOrderCodeSelectionSession;
  public icdCodes: Array<ICDCode>;
  public newIcdCodesArray = [];
  public modalRef: any;
  title: string = "Please Select ICD-10 Codes";
  public serviceSubscription: Subscription;
  private selectedCodes: Array<ICDCode> = [];
  private options: NgbModalOptions = {
    backdrop: "static",
    windowClass: "icd10-codes",
    container: "app-new-test-order-icd10-code-selection-modal",
    keyboard: false,
    size: "lg"
  };

  constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private testOrderService: TestOrderService,
    public router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private store: Store<any>
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceSubscription = this.testOrderService.getICDCodes().subscribe((codes: Array<ICDCode>) => {
      this.icdCodes = codes;
    });
    this.store
      .select("codeSelectionSession")
      .subscribe((session: TestOrderCodeSelectionSession) => {
        // checks for null and undefined
        if (session == null) {
          this.store.select("testOrder").subscribe((testOrder: TestOrder) => {
            this.codeSelectionSession = new TestOrderCodeSelectionSession();
            this.store.dispatch(
              new SetTestOrderCodeSelectionSession(this.codeSelectionSession)
            );
          });
        } else {
          this.codeSelectionSession = session;
        }
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.template, this.options);
    });
    this.serviceSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      //for selected icd
      if(params.selectedIcdCodes) {
        this.selectedCodes = JSON.parse(params.selectedIcdCodes);
      }
      this.codeSelectionSession.SelectedCodes = lodash.concat(this.codeSelectionSession.SelectedCodes, this.selectedCodes);
      //for icd id
      this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds = lodash.concat(this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds, params.icd10Codes);
      this.newIcdCodesArray = lodash.concat(this.newIcdCodesArray, params.icd10Codes);

      this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds = lodash.uniq(this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds);

      let difference = lodash.difference(this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds, this.newIcdCodesArray);
      this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds = lodash.differenceBy(this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds, difference);  //remove the difference
    });
  }

  onCheckboxUpdate(selected: boolean, icdCode: ICDCode) {
    this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds = this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds.filter(
      codeId => codeId !== icdCode.Id
    );
    this.codeSelectionSession.SelectedCodes = this.codeSelectionSession.SelectedCodes.filter(
      code => code.Id !== icdCode.Id
    );
    if (selected) {
      this.codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds.push(icdCode.Id);
      this.codeSelectionSession.SelectedCodes.push(icdCode);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.modalRef.close();
    });
    this.serviceSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The second test should pass as well. I don't know what i am doing wrong here.

Another method i tried. 
This is my specfile by doing this its showing me Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null

```
beforeEach(async() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewTestOrderICD10CodeSelectionModalComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
//    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.h5')).nativeElement.innerText;
//    element  = de.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("New Test Order ICD10 Coed Selection Modal Should be created", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Should have a title', () => {
    //expect(element.textContent).toContain(component.title);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal-title')).nativeElement.innerText;
    expect(de).toContain(component.title);
  });
```

This is my html file

```
<ng-template #icd10codes let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <form role="form" #icdCodeSelectionForm="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="material-icons clickable text-dimmed" (click)="onBackButtonClick()" [routerLink]="['/test-order/create/details']">arrow_back</span>
      <h5 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn square-btn" (click)="update()">ADD CODES</button>
      <div class="icd-search">
        <app-search-list (onSearchInputUpdate)="onSearchUpdate($event)"></app-search-list>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 text-dimmed pad-left-45">ICD-10 Codes</div>
        <div class="col-8 text-dimmed">Description</div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-border"></div>
      <div class="code-list">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let icdCode of icdCodes; let odd = odd" [ngClass]="{'isOdd': odd}">
          <div class="col-3 pad-left-45">{{ icdCode.Code }}</div>
          <div class="col-8 text-dimmed">{{ icdCode.ShortDescription }}</div>
          <div class="col-1">
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="custom-control-input"
                  [ngModel]="codeSelectionSession.ICDCodeIds.indexOf(icdCode.Id) !== -1"
                  (ngModelChange)="onCheckboxUpdate($event, icdCode)"
                  [name]="icdCode.Id">
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: It is not finding element.textContent because your thread(async) running before having any values in element.textContent

Comment: @ShashankVivek i tried but its still not working may be its because of my html file i closed it in ng-template ?

Comment: @SalmanAhmad : what is the condition to render `#icd10codes` on html  ?? Please update entire html code in the post and `not` in the comments :) . `ng-template` is not rendered by default. So, your test case wont find it

Comment: @ShashankVivek Thanks for taking the time i have updated it with my html code :)

Comment: @ShashankVivek I have updated and attached my entire HTML File + .TS file.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad : are u sure that it all the html. Reason, I am asking is because `ng-template` doesn't render on its own. Unless you have `ng-container`. Take a look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-template-vlgpga?file=app/app.component.html. See how last `ng-template` is not rendered although it's on html file

Comment: @ShashankVivek Yes this is the full html file. Actually what is happening here is this components ng-template only gets true when you click on this components field on its parent component. So when i am testing its not actually loading the component thats the reason now after trying your described method of writing test its showing this error **Expected undefined to contain Please Select ICD-10 Codes** i guess i would have to implement it differently .. I appreciate you taking the time and look into this you helped me alot Thanks :)

Comment: @SalmanAhmad: Now it makes sense. Let me see what we can do in unit test. I have never seen this kind of implementation. Normally,we can do `*ngIf` on the component selector of child under `parent component`.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad Please check my updated answer. Its a working example. i missed this question somehow but suddenly I stumbled across the same situation

Comment: @SalmanAhmad did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing `element  = de.nativeElement;` in `beforeEach()`, so the `element` contains the value. 
And, it can be done through

```
it('Should have a title', () => {
    expect(element).toContain(component.title);
});
```

From `de = fixture.debugElement.query(By......`, `de` will be a `HTMLNode`, and using `nativeElement` on this will get you the content. Or, you can directly use `de.textContent` to get the content of the element `de`.

**[Alligator.io Link for Unit testing](https://alligator.io/angular/introduction-unit-testing/)**

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to remove

```
  de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.new-test-order-icd10-code-selection-modal.component'));
```

from `beforeEach` block. Please note that, you are trying to get this value before `fixture.detectChanges();` , so I think it's not a good approach. You must make sure that you get the HTML values after all the angular changes are complete. Try:

```
it('Should have a title', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges(); // No need to add this line if you have it in "beforeEach" block
  const de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.new-test-order-icd10-code-selection-modal.component'));
  const element  = de.nativeElement;
  expect(element.textContent).toContain(component.title);
});
```

### Update

For testing `ng-template` you'll have to do it differently:

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="title">
    {{title}}
</div>
<ng-template #content
             let-modal
             id="ng-modal">
  <div class="modal-header dark-modal">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="justify-content-center flex-column flex-md-row list-inline">
    Body
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularProj';
  @ViewChild('content') modalRef: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

You need to write `spec` file with slightly different way:

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ViewChild, Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="modal"> </ng-container>
    <app-root></app-root>
  `,
})
class WrapperComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild(AppComponent) appComponentRef: AppComponent;
  modal: TemplateRef<any>;
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.modal = this.appComponentRef.modalRef;
  }
}

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let app: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WrapperComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [WrapperComponent, AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WrapperComponent);
    const wrapperComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    app = wrapperComponent.appComponentRef;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(app).toBeDefined();
  }));
  it('should have title in HtmL ', async(() => {
    const titleText = (fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#title').innerText);
    expect(titleText).toBe('AngularProj');
  }));
  it('should have Header in HtmL ', async(() => {
    const headerText = (fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.modal-header.dark-modal'))[0].nativeElement.innerText);
    expect(headerText).toBe('Header');
  }));
});
```

---

1. As you can see, I wrapped the `app-root` with a sample testing component (`WrapperComponent`).
2. Since, `app-root` has `ng-template`, so it won't render on it's own. This creates a tricky situation as we need to render this part of the `app.component`.
3. Expose `ng-template` by creating `@ViewChild('content') modalRef:  TemplateRef<any>;` and then using it to render inside `WrapperComponent`.

I know it seems like a hack but over all the articles I went through, that's how we can achieve this.